# Parse.com Javascript logging out w/ facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, parse-platform

I'm having trouble getting a logged in facebook user in my parse.com application to log out. What is wrong with the code below?

```
function logOff() {
    function thisSuccess(e) {
        console.log(1);
    }
    function thisError(e) {
        console.log(0);
    }
    var u = Parse.User.current();
    Parse.FacebookUtils.unlink(u, {success: thisSuccess,error: thisError});
    u.logOut();
}
```

I've searched everywhere, the best response I got was that the facebook account linked to the user needs to be unlinked as well - I'm not entirely sure whether this is so.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is `Parse.User.logOut();`

Don't unlink the Facebook account, as that use won't be able to log in again. Next time they try to log in with Facebook Parse will create a new user for them.

Comment: Apologies, should be `Parse.User.logOut()`

Comment: I edited and fixed the answer according to the @Meirion comment.